# How do you change a pandas data frame column header to lowercase?

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried various things that I've found here on StackOverflow but nothing has worked so far.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
df_pandas.columns = df_pandas.columns.str.lower()
df_pandas = df_pandas.rename(columns={'Date': 'date'})
df_pandas = df_pandas.reset_index( )
```

All the column headers changed to lowercase except `Date`: https://i.imgur.com/pQUmmmq.png 
I've tried renaming the column but that didn't work either.

Comment: Date was in the index, then you reset the index. So switch your final two lines. Reset the index *then* rename the column.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```py
df_pandas.columns = map(str.lower, df_pandas.columns)
```

Comment: does this assign the list or an iterator?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what mechanical_meat said above, you should reset index first before changing column names to lower case like so:

```
df_pandas = df_pandas.reset_index()
df_pandas.columns = df_pandas.columns.str.lower()
```

Comment: This worked. I was sure I had tried this before but perhaps I forgot to refresh the cell in Jupyter. Thanks.